# Listview crashed after launch

Tags: android, listview, android-manifest, runtime-error, logcat

My application crashes moments after my list-view is launched. My listview is the fist activity ran in the program. I have no compiling errors and do not understand the logcat errors received. I think the issue may be in my manifest. Any assistance would be appreciated. Below is my logcat and manifest.

Logcat:

```
 07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
 07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.loginplus.home.ListProvider from ProcessRecord{41c4be20 1448:com.example.listviewrefresh/10041} (pid=1448, uid=10041) that is not exported from uid 10040
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2201)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4024)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1612)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:918)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:305)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     ... 4 more
```

Listview activity:

```
 public class LoginList extends FragmentActivity implements   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);

loginList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

webLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);



//Specify fields to display in the list
String[] from = new String[] {ListProvider.COLUMN_NAME_SITE};

//Bind fields to listview
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.loginlist};

// Create CursorAdapter and set it to display
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0 );

loginList.setAdapter(adapter);

getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader( 0, null, this);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);

Cursor clickedObject = (Cursor)loginList.getItemAtPosition(0);

Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getsName());
loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getwUrl());
loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getuName());
loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getpWord());
loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getlNotes());

updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0); 
} 

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
startActivity(webLoginIntent);
}

 @Override
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int ignored, final Bundle args) {

String [] columns = { ListProvider.COLUMN_ROWID, ListProvider.COLUMN_NAME_SITE};
CursorLoader cursorloader = new CursorLoader(this, ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, null);

return cursorloader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset (Loader<Cursor> loader) {
adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.listviewrefresh"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".LoginDB"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.LOGINDB" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginDetails"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.LOGINDETAILS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateDeleteLoginList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.UPDATEDELETELOGINLIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPlusActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.LOGINPLUSACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".dataStore"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.DATASTORE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
android:authorities="com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider"
android:multiprocess="true"
android:exported="false"
android:readPermission="com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider.READ_DATABASE"
android:writePermission="com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"
android:name="com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider"></provider>       
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: We need more information about the listview adapter you use.

Comment: Post the asynctask code

Comment: @FD_ listview activity has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of looks like you might be porting an app, no?

Without seeing the details of the `ListProvider` class you're using we can't know for sure, but it looks like your `ListProvider.CONTENT_URI` is the wrong URI.

The error message is saying that you can't access `com.loginplus.home.ListProvider`, not `com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider` which is in your manifest.

If that is, in fact, a content provider from another application, it will error like this if the `android:exported` attribute is false.

To fix it, just update your `ListProvider.CONTENT_URI` to match the one in the manifest or, if you are trying to talk to another app, add `android:exported=true` to the other app's content provider.

Answer (score 1):

As per the logcat

```
07-16 22:42:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.loginplus.home.ListProvider from ProcessRecord{41c4be20 1448:com.example.listviewrefresh/10041} (pid=1448, uid=10041) that is not exported from uid 10040
```

It is trying to open some provider(`com.loginplus.home.ListProvider`) which I cannot see in your manifest.

Ideally it should have been opening `com.example.listviewrefresh.ListProvider`, do you have any other provider?